# How to run Twilio API code using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am using twilio api code in jquery,its working fine.
but i want to implement it in pure javascript,how can i do that with only javascript?

My code is here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){

        var SID = "AC654656****************"
        var Key = "df5456**************"

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',

url: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + SID +'/Messages.json',
            data: {
                "To" : "+919580834781",
                "From" : "+12018647238",
                "Body" : "Test"
            },
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(SID + ':' + Key));
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

can anyone please suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We do not recommend you use front end JavaScript to make calls to the Twilio API. It requires you to embed your Account Sid and Auth Token in your front end (or make it accessible from your front end) which means that an attacker could steal your credentials and use them to abuse your account.

We recommend you perform any actions with the Twilio API on the server. We do have a Node.js module on npm to make that easy to work with. Here's an example of [sending an SMS message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages) with the Node.js module:

```
var client = require("twilio")(YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID, YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN);

client.messages.create({
  body: "Hello",
  to: TO_NUMBER,
  from: FROM_NUMBER
}).
  then(function(result) {
    console.log("Message sent!");
  }).
  catch(function(err) {
    console.log("Error sending message: ", err);
  })
```

Check out this blog post [introducing the Twilio Node.js module](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/03/introducing-the-twilio-module-for-node-js.html) for more information.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Yes its not secured to use it directly in webpage script, but am in need to use Twilio code using an Extension.so i require only javascript to do so... or else anyother method is there to call twilio api using content script in chrome extension?

Comment: Won't an extension need to get published with all your credentials too? Then that can just be unpacked and your account stolen.

Comment: yes its also not secured. Thanks, is there anyother way to call twilio api with my extension?How can i achieve this>

Comment: You should host a server which your extension can make calls to in order to initiate calls or messages via Twilio. That way you just need to store your credentials on the server and they won't be available publicly.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. ll try this method.

Comment: @philnash can you please point me to a source where I can see a client-server implementation using node.js? I see a lot of docs on server-side. I'd like to learn how to create a custom message on client side and post it to the server so Twilio can process and send it as SMS. Thank you.

Comment: @tonkihonks13 sure! [This application I wrote a while back](https://github.com/philnash/sms-messages-app/) sends and shows received messages for a number. [The front end is this form](https://github.com/philnash/sms-messages-app/blob/master/views/new.hbs) and [the server side is handled here](https://github.com/philnash/sms-messages-app/blob/master/routes/index.js#L54-L74). Let me know if that helps!